# pagination - 10 pages per page

Tags: php, pagination

I have a pagination script that displays a list of all pages like so:
`prev [1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8][9][10][11][12][13][14] next`
But I would like to only show ten of the numbers at a time:
`prev [3][4][5][6][7][8][9][10][11][12] next`

How can I accomplish this? Here is my code so far:

```
<?php
/* Set current, prev and next page */
$page = (!isset($_GET['page']))? 1 : $_GET['page']; 
$prev = ($page - 1);
$next = ($page + 1);

/* Max results per page */
$max_results = 2;

/* Calculate the offset */
$from = (($page * $max_results) - $max_results);

/* Query the db for total results. 
   You need to edit the sql to fit your needs */
$result = mysql_query("select title from topics");

$total_results = mysql_num_rows($result);

$total_pages = ceil($total_results / $max_results);

$pagination = '';

/* Create a PREV link if there is one */
if($page > 1)
{
    $pagination .= '< a href="?page='.$prev.'">Previous</a> ';
}

/* Loop through the total pages */
for($i = 1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++)
{
    if(($page) == $i)
    {
        $pagination .= $i;
    }
    else
    {
        $pagination .= '< a href="index.php?page='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>';
    }
}

/* Print NEXT link if there is one */
if($page < $total_pages)
{
    $pagination .= '< a hr_ef="?page='.$next.'"> Next</a>';
}

/* Now we have our pagination links in a variable($pagination) ready to
   print to the page. I pu it in a variable because you may want to
   show them at the top and bottom of the page */

/* Below is how you query the db for ONLY the results for the current page */
$result=mysql_query("select * from topics LIMIT $from, $max_results ");

while ($i = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $i['title'].'<br />';
}
echo $pagination;
?>
```

Comment: We'd like to answer questions, not doing your job for you.

Comment: how do you intend to automatically move the page, after showing 10 records. You need JS for that you know

Comment: why is your href with a "_" in between

Comment: cuz this is the first time I post something here, and it was shouting smth about link limits when posting first time

Comment: I fixed the href's for you but I'm reluctant to perform anymore edits, lest this question fall into the community wiki pit of doom. I think the reason it was shouting about link limits is because you didn't have your code formatted correctly, so it thought you were actually trying to put links in your post.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

10 next pages

```
for($i = $page + 1; $i <= min($page + 11, $total_pages); $i++)
```

or if you want 5 prev and 5 next

```
for($i = max(1, $page - 5); $i <= min($page + 5, $total_pages); $i++)
```

Comment: thanks for your quick answer, It was realy helpful.. never thought It would be so fast! :)

Comment: ahh.. didn't know about that accept thing. just last question.. How to make that all the time there is constant amount of pages(numbers) displayed. - when I open, it displays pages 1-6, every time when I press next, it adds 1 extra - 1-7; 1-8; 1-9; and closing to the end it removes one by one...

Comment: @arthur: use second for, it works like a 1-10 if you are on page 5, and if you click next you are going to page 6 and have 2-11, on page 7 you have 3-12. And you can accept question by clicking on mark under the votes number on left side of my post.

Comment: I did so, thanks for that, but I was just wondering how to make it show 10 pages at the beginning(on the 1st page), 10 pages in the middle( on the 6th or 7th page) and 10 pages on the last page.. thanks anyway!

Answer (score 6):

I've just been looking for an answer to the same original question, and couldn't find it, so this is what I came up with. I hope someone else finds it useful.

```
$totalPages  = 20;
$currentPage = 1;

if ($totalPages <= 10) {
    $start = 1;
    $end   = $totalPages;
} else {
    $start = max(1, ($currentPage - 4));
    $end   = min($totalPages, ($currentPage + 5));

    if ($start === 1) {
        $end = 10;
    } elseif ($end === $totalPages) {
        $start = ($totalPages - 9);
    }
}

for ($page = $start; $page <= $end; $page++) {
    echo '[' . $page . ']';
}
```

Results:

```
$currentPage = 1;  // [1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8][9][10]
$currentPage = 4;  // [1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8][9][10]
$currentPage = 10; // [6][7][8][9][10][11][12][13][14][15]
$currentPage = 17; // [11][12][13][14][15][16][17][18][19][20]
$currentPage = 20; // [11][12][13][14][15][16][17][18][19][20]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$page = 3;
$totalPages = 33;
$count = 9;
$startPage = max(1, $page - $count);
$endPage = min( $totalPages, $page + $count);

if($page-1 > 0){
    echo '<a class="btn btn-default" href="/search-results?page="'.($page-
1).'"><< Prev</a>';
} 

for($i = $startPage; $i < $endPage; $i++): if($i <= $totalPages):

    echo '<a class="btn btn-<?=$i == $page || $i == 1 && $page == "" ? 
    'success' : 'primary';?>"style="margin-right:2px;" href="/search-
    results?page="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>';

endif; endfor;
if($page < $totalPages){
    echo '<a class="btn btn-default" href="/search-results?page="'.
    ($page+1).'">Next >></a>';
}
```