# cakephp increase pagination page displays

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination

right now it shows: prev 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 next

I need to show all the pages (ie) prev 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 ..and so on

here is the code

```
<?php echo $paginator->prev('Previous'); ?><big>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>|<b>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<?php echo $paginator->numbers(array('separator'=>'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>|<b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;')); ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>|<b>&nbsp;&nbsp;</big>
<?php echo $paginator->next('Next'); ?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [pagination - 10 pages per page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3036909/pagination-10-pages-per-page)

Comment: I wouldn't consider this a duplicate, as this is specifically about (and solved by) the CakePHP PaginatorHelper. Hand-coded pagination links wouldn't be a good solution to this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the CakePHP documentation for the numbers method of the PaginatorHelper](http://api.cakephp.org/class/paginator-helper#method-PaginatorHelpernumbers) you can tell it how many items to display on either side of the current item by specifying the `modulus` option.

Change your second line to this:

```
<?php echo $paginator->numbers(array('modulus'=>PHP_INT_MAX,'separator'=>'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>|<b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;')); ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>|<b>&nbsp;&nbsp;</big>
```